# Mapear classe para deserialização de XML para C#

Tags: c#, xml, desserialização

Preciso mapear esse XML em uma classe do C# para desserializar via [RestSharp Deserialization](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
<items total="1232177" items="100">
    <media id="4779808" thumb="http://mh-2-rest.panthermedia.net/media/previews/0004000000/04779000/04779808_thumb_170.jpg"/>
    <media id="8950240" thumb="http://mh-2-rest.panthermedia.net/media/previews/0008000000/08950000/08950240_thumb_170.jpg"/>
    <media id="12842738" thumb="http://mh-1-rest.panthermedia.net/media/previews/0012000000/12842000/12842738_thumb_170.jpg"/>
</items>
</rsp>
```

A classe que eu mapeei ficou assim:

```
namespace PantherMediaAPI
{
    public class Media
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Thumb { get; set; }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public List<Media> Media { get; set; }
        public string Total { get; set; }
        public string _items { get; set; }

        public Items()
        {
            this.Media = new List<PantherMediaAPI.Media>(); 
        }
    }

    public class Rsp
    {
        public Items Items { get; set; }
        public string Stat { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Porém quando eu recebo a resposta todos os atributos vem populados menos o item `public List<Media> Media { get; set; }`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No que estou errando? Tenho muita dificuldade com XML pois trabalho mais com JSON.

Comment: Já tentou usar o recurso do `Visual Studio` "Paste XML as Classes"?

Comment: De qualquer forma, `public string _items` não deveria ser `public string items`?

Comment: @RicardoPontual o deserializer entende que `_items == items` tanto que eu utilizei esse site:https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/  e ele me retornou a mesma classe

Comment: @RicardoPontual vou testar com o XML as Classes ;)

Comment: #partilGabiarra ...  XmlDeserializer xml = new XmlDeserializer();
            Rsp output = xml.Deserialize<Rsp>(new RestResponse { Content = text,ContentType = "application/xml" });
            var output2 = xml.Deserialize<List<Media>>(new RestResponse { Content = text,ContentType = "application/xml" });
            output.Items.Media = output2;

Answer (score 0):

Penso que para fazer o `Deserialize` é necessário que as classes estejam corretamente configuradas com as *tags* XML.

No exemplo abaixo coloquei, penso eu (não testei), todas as configurações necessárias para que funcione corretamente:

```
[XmlType("media")]
public class Media
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("thumb")]
    public string Thumb { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("items")]
public class Items
{
    [XmlElement, XmlArray("media")]
    public List<Media> Media { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("total")]
    public string Total { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("items")]
    public string _items { get; set; }

    public Items()
    {
        this.Media = new List<Media>();
    }
}

[XmlType("rsp")]
public class Rsp
{
    [XmlElement("items")]
    public Items Items { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("stat")]
    public string Stat { get; set; }
}
```

Tenho apenas dúvidas em relação à classe `Items`, que tem um elemento também com nome `items`, não sei se não dará problemas ao construir o objeto.